# WebAPI token on Header - how to set 30 minutes expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

Let's assume I have a WebAPI that returns a Security Token (a GUID) on the Header of a Login call.

Ideally we would like to receive further calls within the 30 minutes and every time we receive a call, we need to change the token to get another 30 minutes.

Constraint: 
I cannot use the Session.

What's the right way to set an expiration on a specific Header value on a WebAPI environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sending a GUID, you can change your token to structured data. For example: [JWT](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html)

The general steps to generate a token are:

1. Create a structured data includes {id: GUID, exp: time}
2. Serialize it to a string (JSON.net)
3. Encrypt the data (Machine key / Dpapi encryption)
4. Encode the data (Base64)

The steps to receive a token are just reverse the steps above.

After you get the expiration time on server code, you can determine if you need to refresh the token or not. That procedure above is actually what cookie authentication does in ASP.NET.

For token header based auth, it's better to follow OAuth 2.0 spec to use refresh token to extend the token expiration time.

BTW, [Owin OAuth middleware](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/) already supports oauth bearer token. I have a [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx) about how it works in SPA template. You may consider using that instead of inventing your own. Thanks.

[Update]
I just uploaded [another sample project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OWIN-Bearer-Token-d5eeecc2) which simplifies the bearer token authentication without following OAuth 2.0 flow.

Comment: Thanks HS. I'm readying your blog and realize it's also talking about moving controllers on the client. Can you tell me value of doing so? Also does that mean that you have to load all controllers at once on the client before the page can function correctly? Thanks again for the tip !!!

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by controllers? Controller is always a server concept and I never mention that it should be moved to client. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Sorry, I read "Knockout" and somehow I thought i read "Angular". My mistake.

Comment: On your blog is there something specific to the SPA concept or can I use it for a standard WebAPI project that will be consumed by IOS, Java, C++, C# apps ?

Comment: SPA template can be applied to any client. It just has a javascript client sample implementation. If you want to start from a pure web api project, you can create a web api template with individual auth which has almost the same server code as SPA template but without javascript client implementation. BTW. I created another sample project (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OWIN-Bearer-Token-d5eeecc2) which simplify the scenario by removing the use of OAuth server.

Comment: The sample is VS13. I'm ready to download but not sure if this will screw something on my current VS12 projects (like MVC4 did changing some constraints on MVC3 projects). Are u aware of any known problems?

Comment: AFAIK, VS13 should work side by side with VS12 well.

Comment: Hongye, I looked at your sample. Pretty smooth and impressive. But I have to admit I'm still a bit confused why there is a need to get Identify involved on a REST API. Shouldn't each call be totally detached from the server? If so, what would I be missing if I didn't use the Identity but instead store the token on a Database and on each call that requests Database information, by passing the token, I get database attached UserID and from there do whatever that api call expects to do??

Comment: @HongyeSun thanks. fyi your second link does not work. It returns a page that says "This item is not yet published"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you have selected a right solution/Approach.
It is a consumer job to get token refreshed in a proper time(as soon as a token gets expired)
I would suggest to build a separate STS Service that issues tokens to consumers and then this token is sent to the web API web Service(in headers). Web API Service verifies that token was signed with the proper secret key and if it is the case then allows to get the data.

Comment: Sure but my question relates to understanding what's the right way to store the time on the header so that we can decide when it should expire it.

Comment: It depends on token type.